# Does Newtonian capacity increase strictly when mass is spread?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, measure-concentration, potential-theory

We start with two disjoint compact sets A and B with positive capacities. Then, we translate B s.t. $B+rv$ is disjoint from A and B and ,more importantly, $dist(x,y)<dist(x,y+rv)$ for all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. Does this imply

$$Cap(A\sqcup B)<Cap(A\sqcup (B+rv))?$$

We have $\leq $ because contraction maps decrease capacity (Landkoff in chapter "metric properties of capacities"). The map that sents $A\sqcup B+rv$ to $A\sqcup B$ decreases distances.

I will post as I find things.

We have $Cap(A)=[inf_{\mu(A)=1}\int_{A}\int_{A}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{d-2}}d\mu(x) d\mu(y)]^{-1}$. Call the infimum measure $\mu_{A}$ (equilibrium measure).

So the diffulty is in showing that $\mu_{A\sqcup B}\geq \mu_{A\sqcup (B+rv)}$.

Why does there exist measure $\mu'_{A\cup B+rv}$ s.t. $\int\int_{A\cup B} \frac{1}{|x-y|} d\mu_{A\cup B}>\int\int_{A\cup B+rv} \frac{1}{|x-y|} d\mu'_{A\cup B+rv}$?

If we take any measure supported on $A$ and $B+rv$, it is not obvious to me that that the above inequality is true.

If we set $\mu'_{A\cup B+rv}(A):=\mu_{A\cup B}(A)$, how can we shift the measure while keeping the integral lower or equal?

Maybe just define $\mu'_{A\cup B+rv}(B+rv):=\mu_{A\cup B}(B)$

Comment: I did not understand how do you use the Landkof result. Why does there exist a contraction which sends $A$ to $A$ and $B$ to $B+rv$? (I do not think this is true without further restrictions.) And what does your strange sign like $\Pi$ upside down nean? Is this the union?

Comment: The map that sents $A\sqcup (B+rv)$ to $A\sqcup B$ decreases distances. The $\sqcup$ is standard notation for disjoint union.

Comment: I also don't see why your map decreases distances. Your condition that $\textrm{dist}(A,B)$ goes up after translating $B$ does not prevent individual points from $B$ from getting closer to a fixed point in $A$ after translation.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, as a minor curiosity, note that the similarity to an upside-down $\Pi$ is not a coincidence; $\prod$ (`\prod`) right-side up is a product, whereas $\coprod$ (`\coprod`) upside down is a coproduct (set-theoretic, in this case).

Comment: Now the claim seems clear. Since you can just use the same equilibrium measure as before to estimate the $\inf$ (the $B$ part suitably translated), the capacity could only stay the same if the equilibrium measure was supported by $A$ or $B$, but this is impossible because the potential is constant q.e. on $A\cup B$ and $A,B$ have positive capacity.

Comment: @Remling could you add more detail and put it as an answer? Eg. why capacity would stay the same if it was supported on A or B?

Comment: @TKM: I don't think this is interesting enough for an answer. Just write $\int\int \ldots$ as a sum of four parts, corresponding to $A$ or $B$ as the region of integration, and look at what happens to this if you now shift $B$ and that part of the measure (this will not be the new equilibrium measure, but it gives a lower bound on the capacity).

Comment: @TKM: I agree with Christian's last message. The measure cannot be supported by A or B because you said that they are both of positive capacity.